# Is there a way to activate a virtual environment, then run a python script using subprocess within windows?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, subprocess

I would like to first activate a virtual environment in windows.
Then, run a script that uses the libraries from said virtual environment.
The idea would be to run the python file in Task Scheduler.

One attempt was the following:

```
cmd = r"file_loc\Scripts\activate.bat"
file = r"file_loc\python_script.py"

subprocess.run([cmd,"python -m", file])
```

However, the return_code indicates it completed successfully (0), but it doesn't actually run the python file.

Note: I need to activate the virtual environment before running "python_script.py" because it is depended on libraries other than the standard libraries.

Comment: instead of running a file as `python foo.py`, as an example if your virtual environment is named `venv` you would use `venv/bin/python foo.py` in linux. Windows/Mac may be slightly different.

Comment: Oh ok yeah, I would need a Windows solution.